# Fullcalendar 3 - Get current instance on Select function

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I use Fullcalendar 3, and I have several instances of Calendars.

I want to select the current instance on select function, for now I have :

```
$('.calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: moment('2000-01-03'),
    allDaySlot: false,
    selectable: true,
    editable: true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        console.log(this);
       
        // this does nothing
        // before I had $('#calendar').fullCalendar('....');
        this.el.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    allDay: allDay
                },
                false // make the event "stick"
        );

        this.el.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
```

Before I used  `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('....');`, but now I have different instances.

How can I use a function like `renderEvent` inside the select function ? Using the current instance ?

Comment: What happens when you write `this.el.fullCalendar`...? Do you get a specific error? have you tried `this.fullCalendar` or `$(this).fullCalendar`?

Comment: P.s. any specific reason you've got multiple calendars on one page? What are you trying to achieve by that exactly?  I'm just wondering whether there might be another way to do whatever you're thinking of

Comment: I found it, I got multiple calendars because I needed to define open hours for odd & even weeks. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Ok this way is working :

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    this.calendar.el.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                start: start,
                end: end,
                allDay: allDay
            },
            false // make the event "stick"
    );

    this.calendar.el.fullCalendar('unselect');
},
```

And for example, on eventClick event, I had to use another one :

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    if(confirm("Voulez-vous supprimer cet horaire ?")) {
        // delete in frontend
        calEvent.source.calendar.el.fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent.id);
    }
}
```